# Retrieving the place ID of a city with the Google Maps/Places SDK on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have to get the place id of a city using the Google Maps and Google Places SDK-s. I know the `GMSPlacesClient` contains methods for accessing a location *using the place id* but not vice versa.

What I would like to achieve is to send a city's name/zip code/ coordinates or something like that, and get back as a result, the place id identifying that city.

I've been studying the documentation for the `GMSPlacesClient` [at this link](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_places_client) and experimenting with the methods for hours, however I can't seem to achieve this, however basic this capability is.

Let me know if you need me to provide some further info on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the placeID by accessing the .placeID property on a GMSPlace.

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_place

You will need to use this class to get the location using the autocomplete...

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_autocomplete_prediction

You will need to filter your search results using an instance of — GMSAutocompleteFilter()

```
let filter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
filter.type = .city
```

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/reference/group___places_autocomplete_type_filter#gac7ff529f1296d874a5432707bce58671

Comment: That would've been my first guess, but how do get a GMSPlace object from a coordinate?

Comment: LajosDeme I updated my answer to give you the method to get the GMSPlaces using a coordinate. Here is a link to my repo where I did something similar to what you're trying to do (take a look at my method setupPlacesClient() ) — https://github.com/victis23/Inventory-Tracker-Iphone-App/blob/variableVender/IphoneInventoryTracker/Controllers/VendorLocationController/GoogleMapVenderLocation_ViewController.swift

Comment: Thank you! You just saved my day!

Comment: Finally i've found a real good answer. Thank you a lot